# mysql or mariadb is a single line statement with a delimiter possible?

Tags: mysql, bash, mariadb

Due to the way our bash script is consuming a mariadb statement as a single line via a variable, we are having issues using a delimiter. Is there a way to have a delimiter on a single line statement?

```
while read -r tmp;
    do
        chomped_line=${tmp}
        myOut+=("$chomped_line")
    done < <(mysql -u myUn -pmyPw -h myHost -D myDb --batch --xml<<<${mySqlVar})
```

mariadb that works as script on multi line

```
delimiter | 
select @myCount .... from table WHERE (myVal='valA' AND active=1); IF (@myCount > 0) THEN start transaction; .....; commit; END IF|
```

Does NOT work as single line when passed via ${mySqlVar}, stops after `delimiter |`

```
delimiter | select @myCount .... from table WHERE (myVal='valA' AND active=1); IF (@myCount > 0) THEN start transaction; .....; commit; END IF|
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In MySQL/MariaDB, `DELIMITER` is used only for building stored routines.  Toss that.

The command `mysql` is perfectly happy to take multiple SQL statements separated by `;`.

```
$ echo "SELECT @x := NOW(); SELECT @x+INTERVAL 23 HOUR;" | mysql -u me
@x := NOW()
2018-12-07 11:28:51
@x+INTERVAL 23 HOUR
2018-12-08 10:28:51
```

However, I recommend you create a file with the SQL and input it:

```
$ mysql -u me < script.sql
```

Comment: Giving this the correct answer as it is the closest correct answer. Echo'ing out the statement to a tmp.sql file then reading back in does work, where passing the the original variable does not. However a `delimiter` is needed to use the  `IF` compound statement outside of a proceedure on mariadb.

Answer (score 0):

The `DELIMITER` command *must* be followed by a newline. You can't define the delimiter on the same line where you subsequently use that delimiter.

You might want to use `mysql --delimiter ...` so you don't have to use the `DELIMITER` command as part of your input.

Tip: You can learn many things by running `mysql --help` or reading its [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html).